# Specified page content gets repeated when using Ajax to only reload a section of page

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm developing a laravel application with a sidebar and to not reload the whole page when a user clicks on a link I have used this ***script***.

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){

      $('.nav-link').click(function (event) {
        // Avoid the link click from loading a new page
        event.preventDefault();

        // Load the content from the link's href attribute
        $('.container-fluid').load($(this).attr('href'));
    })

    });

 </script>
```

---

and this is the **HTML**

```
  <a class="nav-link" href="/test">
 <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">



      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

This is the page content that the **/test** contains

> ```
>   this is for testing purposes only
> ```

That line gets repeated multiple times. 
I have looked around for many workarounds and looked into laravel render but I couldn't make that work.

Comment: Can you include more of your html?

Comment: yeah but thought that much would be sufficient, just a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong selector since `container-fluid` exist more than once in your layout.

Try this instead or add an id attribute to your main content div :

```
    $('.content .container-fluid').load($(this).attr('href'));
```

Or

```
<!-- Main content -->
<div class="content">
  <div id="my-content" class="container-fluid">
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
<!-- /.content -->
```

With :

```
    $('#my-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There exist two `container-fluid` classes that are the problem.